# Difference between Hybrid encryption and Diffie-Hellman key agreement?

Tags: encryption, diffie-hellman

Can someone explain me the difference between the [Diffie-Hellman key agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) (DH encryption) and [Hybrid encryption?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)

As to my knowledge DH key agreement uses public and private keys to generate a session key between two parties and uses that session key to encrypt the data. Isn't this the mechanism used in Hybrid encryption as well?

Answer (score 1):

[Hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) uses [public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) to exchange a secret key, and [symmetric cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) to encrypt the data. The main reason is that public-key cryptography makes the key exchange easy, while symmetric cryptography is faster.

The [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) is a protocol used along with public-key cryptography. It allows 2 entities to create a shared secret (i.e. the session-key). The DH key exchange will *not* encrypt your data! It will only give you a key that can be used with a symmetric-key algorithm to encrypt the data.

Basically, the DH key exchange is one of the tools used in the first steps (the *key exchange* part) of Hybrid encryption.

---

PS: I found a related question on the Crypto community, you might want to take a look:
["Why is Diffie-Hellman considered in the context of public key cryptography?"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6307/why-is-diffie-hellman-considered-in-the-context-of-public-key-cryptography)